# Python perform mean of np.array

Tags: python

I have a lot of `np.ndarray` who I like to perform a mean of each component... so far I have not idea how to speed up the mean so I'm using a very boaring sum like in this way :

```
 self.bins, self.w1 = [],[]
   
   files = [ 'streigen.000533048.dat',  'streigen.000533049.dat',  'streigen.000533050.dat',  'streigen.0    00533051.dat',  'streigen.000533052.dat', 'streigen.000533053.dat',  'streigen.000533054.dat',  'streigen.0005    33055.dat', 'streigen.000533056.dat']
   
   for i,j in zip(range(len(files)),files):
        self.bins.append(np.genfromtxt('vorcospdf/56.72/'+j ,usecols=(0,), skip_header=0))                   
        self.w1.append(np.genfromtxt('vorcospdf/56.72/'+j,usecols=(1,), skip_header=0)   
        
   w1 = (self.w1[0] + self.w1[1] + self.w1[2] + self.w1[3] + self.w1[4] + self.w1[5] + self.w1[6] + self.    w1[8]) / 9
```

there is some way to make it better in particular when the number of file increase a lot ? (I don't need to make any mean for the `self.bins`)

Comment: Turn your w1 (weights?) into a two-dimensional ndarray, then use `np.mean(self.w1, axis=0)` (or `axis=1`, depending on your goal).

Comment: I would like to perform a mean of the several array in order to obtain an array of the mean of each single component!

Comment: I think if you play around and try what I've suggested in my comment, you'll likely get what you need. If not, please let us know how that does not work for what you intend.

Comment: Do all input files have the same amount of data? And what happened to `self.w1[7]`? That one seems to be missing from your example.

Comment: you are completely right !!! thanks a lot !